# Cómo puedo mandar un dato de un form a otro form para despues compararlo en una funcion de boton?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Lo que planeo hacer es que en mi primera forma se registre el correo y contraseña y que en la siguiente forma esos datos se evalúen con los datos nuevos que se van a ingresar(datos que se van a pedir para iniciar sesión en la siguiente forma) y que estos se comparen cuando el usuario de clik en el botón de  iniciar.

```
if (nombre.Length > 0 && apellido.Length > 0 &&
           Verifica_Correo(correo) == true && contraseña.Length >= 11)
        {
            if(checkBox1.Checked == true && checkBox2.Checked == true &&
               checkBox3.Checked == true && checkBox4.Checked == true)
            {
                logg_ form_loog = new logg_(); //Aquí se va iniciar la forma número dos para poder entrar a la pedida de datos de inicio de sesión 


                form_loog.Show();
            }
        }
```

//Forma uno que pide los datos de registro 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//Forma dos que pide los datos de nuevo para iniciar sesión 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El form de inicio de sesion no deberia ejecutarse desde un form de registro, sino que deberia ser al contrario

El primer form que inicies es el de login y este deberia instanciarse desde el `Main()` de `Program.cs` algo como esto

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        frmLogin frm = new frmLogin();
        frm.ShowDialog();

        if(frm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
            Application.Run(new frmPrincipal());

    }
}
```

entonces en el form de login pondrias un boton que abre el form de registro para poder generar los datos.

De esta forma no necesitas comunicarlos formularios ya que ambos deberian acceder a los datos que registras previamente para que quedes disponibles para el form de autenticacion.